# How to use .on in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component that using the tagify library. I am getting an error that `tagify.on` is not a function.

How do I do the `.on` in React? How do I add these `.on` methods to the this tagify component that I'm creating?

Do I make them all constants and arrow functions?

```
const tagify = new Tagify(tagsInput, {
    //  mixTagsInterpolator: ["{{", "}}"],
    mode: 'mix',
    pattern: /@|#/,
    here) tagTextProp: 'text',

    whitelist: fields.map(function(item) {
        return typeof item == 'string' ? {
            value: item
        } : item
    }),
    dropdown: {
        enabled: 1,
        position: 'text',
        mapValueTo: 'text',
        highlightFirst: true
    },
    callbacks: {
        add: console.log, // callback when adding a tag
        remove: console.log // callback when removing a tag
    }
});

let tagsInput = createRef();

tagify.on('input', function(e) {
    < -- - this is giving error tagify.on is not a
    function
    const prefix = e.detail.prefix;

    if (prefix) {

        if (e.detail.value.length > 1)
            tagify.dropdown.show(e.detail.value);
    }

    console.log(tagify.value)
    console.log('mix-mode "input" event value: ', e.detail)
});

tagify.on('add', function(e) {
    < -- - this is giving error tagify.on is not a
    function
    console.log(e)
});
```

Comment: Is the object initialized at that point? What if it's undefined?

Comment: What should that `.on` be from? Why do you expect that this should exist? I don't see that this anywhere documented in the tagify documentation.  Or do you refer to [Tagify jQuery version](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#jquery-version), but then why do you want to use that one if you are using react?

Comment: Should I share the full component? its about 400 lines or so...

Comment: Since you tagged the question with [tag:reactjs], why not use the `<Tags>` React component? The component accepts `onChange`, `onInput`, `onAdd`, etc. event handlers. Have a look at the [Tagify React documentation](https://github.com/yairEO/tagify#react). There is also a live demo that demonstrates different use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Looking after the docs,

`.on` method is provided for jQuery, you don't need it. You can use it on callbacks:

```
callbacks: {
  "input": (e) => console.log(e.detail))
```

Answer (score 0):

Had something similar to yours. Suggestion:

- Write all of the upper code in a function (except the `let tagsInput = createRef();` line, move it out). Call it **configureTagify** or whatever.
- Call it in an appropriate place (in the beginning for e.x, the componentDidMount's equivalent)

.

```
useEffect(() => {  
  ...  
  configureTagify();  
  ...  
}, []);
```